First prime such that $\{p+h_1,...,p+h_k\}$ contains $k$ consecutive primes?
I have the following question: Given an admissible k-tuple $\mathcal{H}$, is there any theorem that helps me calculate or approximate the first prime $p$ such that the set $\{p+h_1,p+h_2,...,p+h_k\}$ contains k consecutive primes? Any result that helps me to further calculate some $p $ could help (I was thinking of something analogous to Linnik's theorem). Thanks

are you looking for this: $7+10=17$, $17+20=37$, $37+30=67$, $67+40=107$, $107+50=157$...and $11+20=31$, $31+30=61$, $61+40=101$, $101+50=151$, $151+60=211$, $211+70=281$...? You can get the same thing using $23+20=43$...But I think if you want to keep p constant, it will be harder.
